# Return cell value with Worksheet_Change after inserting or deleting a row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to insert the current date and username as soon as the word "done" is inserted in some of the cells in the column S.

It works until I delete or insert a new row.

Then I get the error

> 13

and the line `If Target.Value = "Done" Then` is highlighted.

```vb
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S:S")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Done" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 7).Value = Date
        Target.Offset(0, 8).Value = Environ("username")
    Else
        Target.Offset(0, 7).ClearContents
        Target.Offset(0, 8).ClearContents
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When you delete or insert a row Target is a reference to that row - and it intersects column S.  So, when the code runs the Target is, for example, `$7:$7` and you're checking if that equals Done.  I'd also check that the `Target.Count=1` as well.

Comment: Also, add `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the start and back to True at the end.  Lines like  `Target.Offset(0, 7).Value = Date` change the value on the sheet, so the `Worksheet_Change` event will fire again for that, and then again for the next row before returning to the original change event that started it all.

Answer (score 3):

Add `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub` as first line of the procedure.

By that, if a row gets inserted or deleted, the rest of the code won't get executed.

Answer (score -1):

thank you for your reply. I have found the way out, hier is my updated code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S:S")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Target.Value = "Erledigt" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 7).Value = Date
            Target.Offset(0, 8).Value = Environ("username")
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 7).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 8).ClearContents
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you adding your own answer when @Ike gave exactly the same answer an hour before you? Please acknowledge his answer by setting it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Add `On Error Resume Next` just before `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S:S")) Is Nothing Then`

this works

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` is no good idea. It will hide **all** errors. In this case sub should only run when one cell in column S has changed. It is possible to check for those conditions without ignoring errors!